# Admob causes NullPointerException in android apps

Tags: android, admob

Since last week i'm getting a fatal error in my app in production release due some admob bug

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.n com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.AdOverlayInfoParcel.c' on a null object reference
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.k.f(k.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.client.b.a(b.java:1)
       at fy.onTransact(fy.java:4)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:662)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzgu.zzb(zzgu.java:21)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzarl.onUserLeaveHint(zzarl.java:54)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity.onUserLeaveHint(AdActivity.java:32)
       at android.app.Activity.performUserLeaving(Activity.java:7470)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnUserLeaving(Instrumentation.java:1476)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performUserLeavingActivity(ActivityThread.java:4034)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4016)
       at android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem.execute(PauseActivityItem.java:45)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

I was not able to reproduce the problem in test. but as the stack shows it is caused due some inner call of the admob api responding to android native events.

the versions i'm using:

```
'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0"
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'
```

Comment: Is error scenario similar to this ? https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/513

Comment: Same problem here.Waiting for Admob sdk developers to fix it.

Comment: I am getting the exact same crash reports lately, has this issue been filed somewhere? @robert since you say that you are waiting for Abmob to fix it, I assume they are aware of this issue. Do you have a link to the bug report?

Comment: facing same issue. Was anyone able to find a solution?

Comment: Same crash on 19.5.0. I also found some developers report the error on 19.6.0

Comment: Same issue on 19.7.0

Comment: We observe it happens in AdActivity, which I believe is interstitial ad. Any one seeing see these errors without serving interstitial at all?

Comment: Same issue here but according to Crashanalytics it happens mostly in Android 8 devices and in background mode.

Answer (score 2):

Best is try logging the Ad response id to basically see if there is a certain type of Ad crashing the App. If yes you need to search for Ad in Ad manager and block it from serving.
https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/crashlytics

Comment: I got above response from Admob support team so whoever for no reason gave a down vote either hasnt worked on Admob or does not understand how Ads work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I Don't know the Perfect Solution of this because I think there is a bug in
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0` or `19.6.0`
look at this [thread](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/1jbYTl4T28U/m/DkE550TKBwAJ)

the hacky solution is to use
 `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been addressed by Google Admob SDK team.
Based on them, the issue should no longer appear in a high frequency, and will be completely resolved in the near future.

From what i can see, i had zero occurrence of the issue in crashlytics after their feedback

Complete thread can be found here:
https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/J6yNYabpeB0/m/zIkSSLEwAgAJ
I was opened by someone else, and i had followed it up with them sometime later.

Comment: it depends on your app usage, my app has over 30k daily users... so if 1% of them get the error is a lot of erros poping up in crashlytics and it starts to send me those alerts "many sessions are crashing" "alert of errors" and all stuff... i dont like it

Answer (score 0):

The error disappeared with these lines:

```
gradle (app)
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ...
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```

and in manifest

```
<application
    ...
    ...
    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
    ...
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score -1):

Update to latest version and check Internet permissions manifest.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'
```