# NullPointerException at com.google.android.gms.ads

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, admob

From Google Play developer console I'm getting the following crash:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.k.h (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204204100@204204100000.336078696.336078696)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.client.b.bx (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204204100@204204100000.336078696.336078696:1)
  at gg.onTransact (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204204100@204204100000.336078696.336078696:4)
  at android.os.Binder.transact (Binder.java:380)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzgu.zzb
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzarl.onUserLeaveHint
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity.onUserLeaveHint
  at android.app.Activity.performUserLeaving (Activity.java:6163)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnUserLeaving (Instrumentation.java:1320)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performUserLeavingActivity (ActivityThread.java:3237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:3214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:155)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1328)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5298)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:911)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

for example on this device: Huawei Y5 - Android 5.1 (SDK 22)
using `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.5.0`

I was unable to report this on https://support.google.com/admob/ cause any
kind of report submission fails.

Any suggestment about the crash? Workaround? Fix? Thank you in advance

Comment: hello, i am facing a similar problem, where you able to find any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64638098/admob-causes-nullpointerexception-in-android-apps